# Notification not triggered with AlarmManager

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, alarmmanager

I followed couple tutorials about setting repetitive notifications every 24 hours, below is my code which is not working, not sure why. Also, I want to call a method when the notification is clicked, that's why I put an extra "NotiClick" with the notification Intent.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Menu.class);
    intent.putExtra("NotiClick",true);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.luckywheel)
            .setContentTitle("Alarm Fired")
            .setContentText("Events to be Performed").setSound(alarmSound)
            .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(NotificationID.getID(), mNotifyBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Here is what I have in my Menu.class in OnCreate method where I set my alarm.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 13);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent( Menu.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Menu.this, 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) Menu.this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Log.d("NOTIFICATION", "SET " + am);
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras == null)
        {
            //Cry about not being clicked on
        }
        else if (extras.getBoolean("NotiClick"))
        {
            //Notification clicked
        }

    }
```

Also, I have set the receiver in Manifest:

```
 <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/>
```

Also, my phone is an Huawei, if it has some importance at all. I have set the calendar to be 1 minute above installation so I can get the notification but nothing happened.
Any ideas about why this isn't working ?

Comment: Have you registered your broadcast receiver (AlarmReceiver) in the manifest?

Comment: @segfault404 yes, I have updated my question :)

Answer (score 0):

For API >= 26, you need to set the `NotificationChannel`:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
        context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.luckywheel)
        .setContentTitle("Alarm Fired")
        .setContentText("Events to be Performed").setSound(alarmSound)
        .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

//create notification channel
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("custom_id","custom_name",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    channel.setDescription("custom_description");
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
notificationManager.notify(NotificationID.getID(), mNotifyBuilder.build());
```

Add this and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: Where I should put this ?

Comment: Edited, take another look @Adrian